# Laravel 5.1 : Passing Data to View Composer

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm using view composers in Laravel 5.1: nice. *But how can I pass parameters to a view composer*?

In my case I send week info (previous, current, next week, including the dates) to my view with de view composer. The current week is variable, not only from an url, but also from the controller.

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
   // I need a parameter here (integers)
}
```

Comment: @craig_h To the view composer, because I have to do business logic.

Comment: can you show an example of a context from where you want to pass these parameters?

Comment: The place is the controller. But the controller can get de parameters from url, but also from an other class. Then, I cannot use Request::get(), but I need to pass to view composer. Understand? ;-)

Comment: ok, could you use a wrapper class for the view composer, pass data to the class from the controller, and finally call the compose method accessing the data passed from he controller ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Your scenario is right possible. I never want to use Request::get() in my view composer: terrible. In Laravel 4, I see that you can use $view->getData()....

Comment: @HenriSchellingerhout : i've added an answer, check if it could be useful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have to pass parameters from a controller to a view composer, you can create a wrapper class for the composer and pass data to it whenever needed. Then, when you're done setting up you data, you can compose the view:

**ComposerWrapper class**

```
public function __construct(array $data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

public function compose()
{        
    $data = $this->data;

    View::composer('partial_name', function( $view ) use ($data) 
    {
        //here you can use your $data to compose the view
    } );
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    //get the data you need
    $data = ['first_value' = 1]; 

    //pass the data to your wapper class
    $composerWrapper = new ComposerWrapper( $data );

    //this will compose the view
    $composerWrapper->compose();

   //other code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very beautiful!

Comment: I have a similar situation for multiple views. In that case, I need to write some code in multiple functions in the controller. Is there any alternate solution for this?

Answer (score 10):

All the data you pass to your view in the controller will be available in the view controller. Use the `getData` method on the view instance like this:

```
$view->getData()["current_week"];
```

In your particular case, you can do this:

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
   $current_week = $view->getData()["current_week"];
   //use $current_week as desired 
}
```

You can also get the data in the route (route parameters) from the request like this:

```
request()->route()->getParameter('week_number');
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a new feature since the question was asked, but IMO this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: It also looks like you can just use `$view->current_week`. The magic _get() method on View should handle it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to pass some data to the view composer from controller then you can use sessions. Set the data from the controller in the session and you can get data from session in the view composer. This did the trick for me without doing any complex stuff

**Controller**

```
    public function index()
    {
       session(['key' => 'value']);
       return view('your_view');
    }
```

**View Composer**

```
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $data = session('key');
        return $view->with('your_data',$data);
    }
```

Comment: I'd rather not pollute the session with data only needed to build the view.