# How do I send data to partial views from controller in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have setup my navigation menu from a ViewComposer (see laravel view composers: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers)  like this

```
View::composer('partials.nav', function ($view) {
            $view->with('menu', Nav::all());
        });
```

What I need is that from some controllers to setup which navigation item is active, ie "current section".

**Question**:

How do I send from some controllers a variable to "partials.nav" like `currentNavItem`?

Do I send it with the rest of the variables for returned view?

like

```
return view('page.blade.php",$viewVariables + $optionalVariablesForPartialsViews);
```

It looks spammy

**Side notes**:

- I use laravel 5.6

**Later edit**

It looks [Laravel 5.1 : Passing Data to View Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153072/laravel-5-1-passing-data-to-view-composer?rq=1) might be an options. I will try and get back .

Answer (score 0):

Because the `$variable` you want to send differs in different controller's actions yes you need to specify the `$variable`

```
return view('page.blade.php",$viewVariables,$variablesForPartialsViews);
```

of course you might need to set a default value for the $variable in order to avoid `undefined variable error`

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the parameters.
for exemple:

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with('page', $this->getPage());
}

public function getPage()
{
    $viewVariables = 2;
    $optionalVariablesForPartialsViews = 1;
    return $viewVariables + $optionalVariablesForPartialsViews;
}
```

Comment: On what class do you have these methods? On the ViewComposer class? How do I send from the Controller data to the composer?

Answer (score 0):

Under your app folder make a class named yourClassNameFacade. Your class would look like this.

```
class yourClassNameFacade extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'keyNameYouDecide';
    }
}
```

Then go to the file app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php and add to the register function

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('keyNameYouDecide', function (){
            //below your logic, in my case a call to the eloquent database model to retrieve all items.
            //but you can return whatever you want and its available in your whole application.
            return \App\MyEloquentClassName::all();
        });
    }
```

Then in your view or any other place you want it in your application you do this to reference it.

view is the following code:

```
{{ resolve('keyNameYouDecide') }}
```

if you want to check what is in it do this:

```
{{ ddd(resolve('keyNameYouDecide')) }}
```

anywhere else in your code you can just do:

```
resolve('keyNameYouDecide'))
```